# MySQL re-arranging order of columns with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Any help on re-ordering the columns in MySQL using phpMyAdmin? Is it called cardinality? I have created tables, but need to re-arrange the order of the columns due to an export script i have. It exports based on the arrangements. E.g. I want columns:

```
Apple | Cherry | Banana
```

changed to:

```
Apple | Banana | Cherry
```

Comment: Be less vague. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I have edited the question

Comment: Adding the word "specific" into your question does not make it so.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Its more clear now.

Comment: sounds like, you don't know sql and how to use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt, the OP is talking about reordering COLUMNs, you are talking about reordering ROWs. Big difference.

Comment: thanks @johan you are right :-) I still have a problem to understand column/row in english :( Sorry karto, my fault

Comment: re-ordering columns but not rows.

Comment: Cardinality is something totally different. Cardinality refers to the number of different values a column can take. A boolean field has low cardinality, a autoincrement field has high cardinality (every row is different)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP myAdmin - Change Field Order (Move Up Or Down)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962448/php-myadmin-change-field-order-move-up-or-down)

Comment: I put a graphic answer below. In case you get stuck on this. Took me ages to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the ALTER TABLE with MODIFY COLUMN command.  Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY COLUMN Hobby VARCHAR(20) FIRST;
```

I don't know whether or not there's a GUI way to do it in phpmyadmin, but normal SQL queries should work, too.

Comment: ↓↓↓ There now is a very very easy GUI solution to this in phpMyAdmin now! (As I noted in my answer below ↓↓↓. 7 YEARS ago!!! ↓↓↓)  I'm just adding this as this is a LONG lived question that people are STILL coming to this and phpMyAdmin makes it very very easy to reorder columns now. **(PS I hope this is considered OK. If this is bad form please delete this message. *No disrespect meant to @King Skippus who gave an excellent answer in 2011.*)**

Answer (score 72):

phpMyAdmin has finally included this feature in the most recent version (4.0 and up).

Go to the "Structure" view for a table, click the Change button on the appropriate field, then under "Move column" select where you would like the field to go.

Comment: Yay. This answer belongs on http://stackoverflow.com/q/1962448/673991 too.  With a screenshot FTW.

Answer (score 45):

OP asked how to change column order **in phpMyAdmin**.

**NB:** phpMyAdmin keeps making changes but, as of **Nov 2019**, this is still correct.

**1) Click on "Structure".**

[image]

**2) Next click on "Move columns" at the bottom.**

[image]

**3) and voila just drag and drop!** (Very modern for dear old myPhpAdmin!)

[image]

Comment: The move column feature wasn't available yet at the time of the question. Great they brought it.

Comment: Yep I just added that in case another poor soul in trouble like me happened by. That is why I called it the ever changing answer. Lots has changed since the OP.  Oh and I added a pic cause I could not see the damned thing.

Comment: Thanks, @BeNice for this! I didn't see that option.

Answer (score 22):

To reorder columns, pop-up a query window and use the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ... FIRST|AFTER ...
```

Unfortunately you will have to retype the entire column definition. 
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html  Example:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY COLUMN cherry VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER banana;
```

May vary depending on your MySQL version, but this syntax appears to work since version 3.23.

Comment: Thanks; but can it help re-arrange the order of the columns?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you will have to (1) pop up a query window, and (2) respecify the attributes of each column you rearrange.  For example:

```
ALTER TABLE test.`new table`
  MODIFY COLUMN cherry unsigned int(10) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
  AFTER banana
```

Table layout before change:

```
`apple`  varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`cherry` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`banana` varchar(45) NOT NULL
```

Table layout after change:

```
`apple`  varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`banana` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`cherry` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```