# Change column order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Is it possible to **change the order** of *columns* in MySQL (using phpMyAdmin XAMPP) by which they appear without dropping the current table?

Comment: Dup: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962448/php-myadmin-change-field-order-move-up-or-down

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
    MODIFY COLUMN `column_name1` varchar(100) AFTER `column_name2`;
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about phpMyAdmin, but you can certainly do that with an SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
CHANGE COLUMN `oldname` `newname` *column_definition* [AFTER|BEFORE] `colname`;
```

Comment: ...and you can use phpmyadmin to run that query so the answer would be yes.

Comment: Hi, this showed errors on running the sql query                       ALTER TABLE 'teachers-final' 
CHANGE COLUMN 'Field' 'Fields' varchar(20) [AFTER] 'Name';               Any Suggestions?

Comment: simply AFTER. remove brackets

Answer (score 2):

How to do it by using PhpMyAdmin:

- Show table structure
- On the relevant row (i.e. database column) click on "Modify"
- On the extreme right, choose the new position form the "Move field" combo box
- Optionally, click on "Show preview" to see what SQL query will be run (also useful for automatically repeating the procedure in another instance of the same database)
- After closing the preview box, click on "Save"

Done!